# Is it worth generating a new token after every request?

Tags: javascript, security, rest, encryption, https

I'm developing a REST api for a basic application where users can track expenses. I want to handle authentication where a user first submits a request with their credentials (email + password) and gets a response which contains an access token that can be used with further requests (so they don't have to send their user password every time).

The original response also includes a secret "salt." Everytime the user submits a request using the given token, that token becomes invalid and they must generate a new one by hashing the last token used with the secret salt returned in the first response.

I'm requiring HTTPS for all connections.

The idea here is that even if an attacker somehow got the token used, they wouldn't be able to use that token because a) it's likely expired/consumed and b) they don't know the secret salt returned in the original response. Eventually, the secret+token combo expires, and the user will have to re-enter credentials and get a new secret+hash pair.

Is this extra process of rehashing with a secret everytime even worth it? Am I gaining any extra security here? Or am I just over-complicating things with no real benefit?

**Example:**

1. get token:

   ```
   curl -i -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -d '{"email":"test@test.com", "pass":"test"}' \
       https://api.example.com/accesstoken
   ```

   returns a response with {token, secret_salt, expires}. The client
   can forget the user+pass and only hold onto the secret and the most
   recent token, now.
2. get some data: `curl -i -X GET
   https://api.example.com/users/123?t=TOKEN_A`

   returns a response with the user data, assuming TOKEN_A is a valid
   token. Now that token is "consumed" and no longer valid. The user must generate a new
   token by something like `TOKEN_B = sha1(TOKEN_A + secret_salt)`. They can then
   use this new token on a new request.
3. get some more data: `curl -i -X GET https://api.example.com/expenses/123?t=TOKEN_B`

   Now TOKEN_B is consumed, and they have to generate another token.
4. Eventually the secret_salt expires, and the user will have to
   enter credentials and get a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to consider who you are trying to protect from.

The communication channel is https, it is considered secure against eavesdropping and man in the middle attacks. If an attacker could bypass this level of protection he would probably be able to access the salt or even the user credentials. The rolling tokens would not add any extra level of protection.

If an attacker could access the clients computer, he would have access to the secret salt and the latest token, the client must have these stored if he wants to make another request. The rolling token does not add any extra security in this case either, compared to a token that does not change.

The rolling token would probably protect you if an attacker was able to intercept only one message transmitted. In this case the token he would receive would be useless. But it is more likely that someone that could bypass the https protection and intercept one message, would be able to see all communication as well.

If the extra protection that the rolling token offers is minor, the extra complexity it adds is very high. Requiring client and server to have synchronized tokens means that it is possible that the synchronization will break at some time and the user will have to authenticate again using his credentials. Requiring the user to authenticate more often is a greater security risk, it is also bad for user experience.

**To sum up** I consider that the possible extra security that the rolling token adds does not justify the extra complexity. A static token with some expiring policy would be enough.

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was thinking, but it always helps to have another set of eyes on a problem to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same question about a year ago and decided to go with this single token / NONCE approach.
Last month we went back to tokens with longer lifetime, because of the increased complexity and problems with this approach.

First of all because of the problems when sending multiple requests asynchronous. If you can't be shure that the requests come in the given order, do not use single-purpose-tokens. And with the given technology you would limit yourself when queueing your requests, I guess.

But you could still use this salt approach, with validating your response with a client-side created hash from `salt + request-params`. From my point of view, that adds the same level of security as your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The asynchronous thing is a good point I hadn't even considered. I've decided to turn off the token/secret functionality for now, you guys convinced me. I marked Zois's response as answering my question, but this was a great response, too.